# Open a video at a particular time

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5

In my program it is possible to make certain files open externally in whichever program is their file type default. I do this with:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "path of file I want to open";

//open the file:
p.Start();
```

In the case of video files, I want to open the video (in Windows Media Player, - my question is specific to WMV files), and jump to a particular time within the video.

Is it possible to do this? I'm aware that Windows Media Player can be embedded, but I'm keen to avoid this if possible as it will require the inclusion of some DLLs.

Comment: You'll need to call the video player directly instead of letting the shell figure out which application to open based on file type. And then you'll need to figure out what command line parameters to pass to that particular video player to skip to a certain point in the video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to use Windows Media Player the answer is no, there is no such command line parameter, you can find full WMP parameters list [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562624(v=vs.85).aspx).

If you can use VLC it has a [--start-time parameter](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Advanced_Use_of_VLC/#Video_options).

Comment: Thanks. I think the solution I might use in the absence of Windows Media Player is the WPF MediaElement, which can be used within my program and set to start a video at a particular time. It means I have to make my own video player window, but that's OK.

Answer (score 0):

That would depend on whether or not you can actually jump to a certain time and/or frame using the commandline arguments of whichever program is loaded. In this case, Windows Media Player.

Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx

It might be possible to simply do something like:

```
Process.Start(PathToFile, ArgumentsThatIncludeExactTimeOrFrameIndex);
```

Although I am not sure whether or not the arguments wouldn't simply get dumped in case the PathToFile is not an executable but simply a file triggering an association; as you have been doing.